# Where do chart.js positioners go for tooltips to move downward

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am wanting to move the tooltip downwards a few pixels instead of always at the top of each stack (on stacked bar chart).

I found this in the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#position-modes) about `positioners`, but I cannot understand the structure of code and where it should actually go.

```
    Chart.Tooltip.positioners.custom = function(elements, eventPosition) {
        var tooltip = this;

        return {
            x: 0,
            y: -50
        };
    }
```

For reference, you can see where I've tried to place it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1ez0Lo8a/7/) ( not much wonder why its not working )

[Config](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-configuration) seems to have a `position` and `yPadding`, neither of which seem to have effect I want when I put them in the tooltips options:

```
tooltips: {
            yAlign: 'top',
            position: 'nearest',
            yPadding: 50
}
```

`yPadding` distorts the tooltip, I'm not sure why but it muddles up the caret and box.

Comment: maybe set 'yAlign' to 'top' ?

Comment: that works to push it down, but that makes the caret at the top which is not what design is after :(